# Object variables are passed into functions as interface types. Will there be implicit conversion

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type usb interface {
    isok()
}
type phone struct {
}

func (p phone) isok() {
}
func test(u usb) {
    fmt.Printf("typeof u : %T\n", u)
    var _, ok = u.(usb)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("typeof u : usb\n")
    }
}
func main() {
    var p = phone{}
    test(p)
}
```

output：
typeof u : main.phone
typeof u : usb

Will there be implicit conversion or what happened when called function test

Comment: What is the actual question? Take a look at the spec, specifically assignability.

Comment: Note that if `u` is `usb`, and `usb` is an interface type, then the statement `var _, ok = u.(usb)` will ALWAYS result in `ok==true`. Also note that when using the *verb* `%T`, and its corresponding argument is an interface type, then the fmt package will ALWAYS "unpack" what's wrapped in that interface argument and print its *dynamic type*.

Comment: Yes, an implicit interface value will be created. Also note that `fmt.Printf()` expects `interface{}`, so you passing `u` to it, the concrete value stored in `u` will be "repacked" and passed as `interface{}`. See the marked duplicate how to get the dynamic type.